# Where is the difficulty setting?

Tags: metroid-samus-returns

So I've beaten *Metroid: Samus Returns*. I want to try Hard mode.

I can't find how to do it.

(Note: Hard mode, not Fusion mode.)

Seems like it should be simple, but I'm having no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start Hard Mode select New Game on the file you used to beat game and got the Hard Mode unlocked message with.

Comment: Thank you. Seems a little odd but fair enough I suppose.